# Using a variable hangs build process when accessed via import

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, web3js, prisma

GitHub discussion w/ solution: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4038#discussioncomment-111664

I'm building a full-stack app and I'm using Prisma and Web3.  As part of Prisma's build process I use `yarn generate` to compile the schema. I've run into some strange issue where my program is hanging on a return statement.

```js
// ./modules/Wallet.ts
import Web3 from 'web3'

// create a Web3 connection
export const web3 = new Web3(
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/redacted'
    : 'wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/redacted'
)

// load an Ethereum wallet from a private key (env var)
const envWallet = () => {
  if (!process.env.ETH_PRIVATE_KEY) {
    require('dotenv').config()
  }

  const _wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(process.env.ETH_PRIVATE_KEY!)
  // successfully logs the loaded wallet on `yarn generate`
  console.log(_wallet)
  // Issue: `yarn generate` hangs on this line
  return _wallet
}

// initialize the wallet
const wallet = envWallet()

// get the address of the wallet
export const getAddress = () => {
  return wallet.address
}
```

```js
// ./types/Query.ts
// If I omit this file from the schema, it will compile successfully
import { queryType } from '@nexus/schema'
import { getAddress } from '../modules/Wallet'

console.log('Test 1') // logged after the console.log(_wallet)

const Query = queryType({
  definition(t) {
    // simply a GraphQL query that returns the address of the loaded wallet
    t.string('getAddress', {
      nullable: true,
      resolve: (root, args, ctx) => {
        console.log('Test 2') // never hits
        const address = getAddress()
        console.log('Test 3') // never hits
        return address
      },
    })
  },
})

export default Query
```

Comment: If I return a hardcoded string it works, I have lots of experience with Prisma, so I'm familiar with the docs. It's only when I combine Web3 + Prisma that this issue occurs. I can use them on their own just fine

Comment: idk nexus ... `console.log(wallet)` (after `envWallet()`) ? ... define return type for 'getAddress` (TS) ?

Comment: The return type for `getAddress()` is implied (string) and `console.log(wallet)` after `envWallet()` does return a valid object, but `yarn generate` still hangs

Comment: ... but you can help TS (and maybe prisma/cli) with explicit def ? ... looks like a 'prisma/cli' issue ?